# Change the text color of hyperlink in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is the code snippet used for the navbar

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

I tried assigning a class to 'a' element with color "white" but not working..

Comment: I just added the `color` you wanted and it is working as expected, what is it you needed?

Comment: You have assigned color as red. How can you get the white color

Comment: @Vinayak that was me who changed the color to `red` just to make sure, it works..so it is not from OP.

Comment: Now it is working or not .

Comment: that's the problem i tried it on online platform nd its working fine but not in my code

Comment: @kiranvj YUP it's Working!! Give it as an answer.. I will assign it to u

Comment: But that custom class solution should also work. Why is it not working for my code?  @Manjuboyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the bootstrap text class.

Try class `text-white` to the a tag, `<a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">About</a>`

You code didnt work because Bootstrap class has more specificity. Bootstrap rule has `!important`

Bootstrap class

```
.text-white {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

Comment: So, I can use " !Important " for any specificity to be changed?

Comment: @YeshuGarg `!important` works but there are other methods to increase specificity. Check this https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/